# Realm access from incorrect thread Android Retrofit2 RxJava

Tags: android, multithreading, realm, retrofit, rx-java

I'm trying to save my Objects from Retrofit directly into Realm but always getting the Error:"Realm access from incorrect thread".

This is my code:

```
public class RestaurantRepositoryRetrofit implements IRestaurantRepository {

private RestaurantApi mApi;
private Realm realm;
private IMapper<RestaurantJson,Restaurant> mRestaurantMapper;

public RestaurantRepositoryRetrofit(IMapper<RestaurantJson, Restaurant> restaurantMapper) {
    mApi = ApiProvider.getApi().create(RestaurantApi.class);
    mRestaurantMapper = restaurantMapper;
    // Get a Realm instance for this thread
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
**}
@Override
public Observable<Restaurant> getRestaurantById(String restaurantId) {**

    return mApi.getRestaurantById(restaurantId)
            .map(new Func1<RestaurantJson, Restaurant>() {
                @Override
                public Restaurant call(RestaurantJson restaurantJson) {
                    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {

                            realm.copyToRealm(restaurantJson);
                        }
                    });
                    return mRestaurantMapper.transform(restaurantJson);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the Realm instance on the background thread that receives the results of the API.

```
return mApi.getRestaurantById(restaurantId)
        .map(new Func1<RestaurantJson, Restaurant>() {
            @Override
            public Restaurant call(RestaurantJson restaurantJson) {
                try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                     realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                         @Override
                         public void execute(Realm realm) {
                             realm.copyToRealm(restaurantJson);
                         }
                     });
                     return mRestaurantMapper.transform(restaurantJson);
                } 
            }
        });
```

Although if you intend to return a managed RealmObject, you should map out the ID from the saved proxy and then observe on main thread and query with a UI thread instance of Realm using the ID.

Answer (score 1):

`realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();` will return the instance for the thread on which the object is created. But `Observable.map()` is called on the thread the observable sends the message from.

Since the observable comes from Retrofit this can be 2 options:

1. If the CallAdapter was created without specifying a scheduler then it will execute on the thread `Observable.subscribe` was called on.
2. If the CallAdapter was created with a specific scheduler it will be executed on that thread.

If the option that applies is not the same thread as the one where the object is created the "Realm access from incorrect thread" error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Realm [is thread confined](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#threading), which means that you need to make sure that you make calls on Realm objects and the `realm` instance on the same thread that you got the reference on. You probably want to use the scheduling method `observeOn()` from [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) to make sure that you call `realm::executeTransaction()` on the same thread that you got the `realm` instance on.